# How to delete a file named "filen/ame" (with slash) on an ext4 filesystem in debugfs?

Tags: ext4, slash, debugfs

Playing with e2fsprogs `debugfs`, by change/accident, a file named `filen/ame` was created. Obviously the forward slash character `/` serves as the special separator character in pathnames.

Still using `debugfs` I wanted to remove the file named `filen/ame`, but I had little success, since the `/` character is not interpreted as part of the filename?

Does debugfs provide a way to remove this file containing the slash? If so how?

I used:

```sh
cd /tmp
echo "content" > contentfile
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/ext4fs bs=1M count=50
mkfs.ext4 /tmp/ext4fs
debugfs -w -R "write /tmp/contentfile filen/ame" /tmp/ext4fs
debugfs -w -R "ls" /tmp/ext4fs
```

which outputs:

```
debugfs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
 2  (12) .    2  (12) ..    11  (20) lost+found    12  (980) filen/ame
```

I tried the following to remove the `filen/ame` file:

```sh
debugfs -w -R "rm filen/ame" /tmp/ext4fs
```

but this did not work and only produced:

```
debugfs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
rm: File not found by ext2_lookup while trying to resolve filename
```

Apart from changing the content of the directory node manually, is there a way to remove the file using `debugfs` ?

Comment: Does escaping the forwardslash (`filen\/ame`) not work?

Comment: +1, and congratulations. You've managed to find one of the only two cases of "weird character in file name" where just correctly quoting and/or escaping the character in a shell command won't solve the problem. (The other one would be a null byte in a file name, although I suspect that, on most filesystems, that would just truncate the name.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want a fix and are not just trying out `debugfs`, you can have **fsck** do the work for you. Mark the filesystem as dirty and run `fsck -y` to get the filename changed:

```
$ debugfs -w -R "dirty" /tmp/ext4fs
$ fsck -y /tmp/ext4fs
 ...
/tmp/ext4fs was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry 'filen/ame' in / (2) has illegal characters in its name.
Fix? yes
 ...
$ debugfs -w -R "ls" /tmp/ext4fs
2  (12) .    2  (12) ..    11  (20) lost+found    12  (980) filen.ame
```

Comment: `e2fsck` has a `-f`orce option that will lead to a full check “even if the file system seems clean”.

Answer (score 3):

Congradulations on fsck working; if for some reason it didn't work the answer is `ls -i1` followed by `umount` and then `clri`.

Ref: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch23_13.htm

I have actually tested this method.

Comment: If this is Linux (which it seems like), it's worth noting that `clri` isn't a separate command (as it is on some other Unix systems), it's a subcommand inside `debugfs`.

Comment: @hobbs: must make mine unusual then. Oh wait, nvm clri was just echo "clri $2" | debugfs "$1"

Comment: Your instructions require running fsck anyway - which will fix the problem, with the message `Entry 'filen/ame' in / (2) has deleted/unused inode 12.  Clear<y>?` instead of the one noted in the other answer - but doing the clri is an extra step. There doesn't seem to be a way to resolve this purely from within debugfs.

Comment: @Random832: I had fsck not fix it of its own in ages past. :(

Answer (score -1):

If you move the file to a directory, you can then delete the directory with the file in it.

```
mkdir foo 
mv filen* foo
rm -rf foo
```

Comment: This would work for any _other_ awkward filename, but it won't work for a filename that has `/` in it.